# Is there a data-structure similar to JSON in JAVA?

Tags: java, json, data-structures, associative-array

I need to store key-value pairs inside key-value pairs and so on as required by the data.

I tried to achieve this using Hash-Map in java but it didn't work as I expected it to. Since, my data has multiple name->value pairs, but the Hash-Map keeps overwriting the name key's value with the new one.

Say for example, I need to store a list of products and their details for an online store. Which data structure would help me achieve this and how ?

TIA.

Comment: How about redis server? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/index.htm 
It is often referred to as a data structure server since keys can contain strings, hashes, lists, sets and sorted sets

Comment: you do have json library for java provided by json.org. you can use that.

Comment: The problem with using a json library is the performance overhead introduced due to serializing and de-serializing the json string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a 'generic' collection, why not use a Guava [MultiMap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap)  ?

> A collection that maps keys to values, similar to Map, but in which
> each key may be associated with multiple values. You can visualize the
> contents of a multimap either as a map from keys to nonempty
> collections of values ... or as a single "flattened" collection of key-value pairs

However, it sounds like you may really want to model your entities as *proper objects*, with the appropriate attributes etc. Storing collections of collections of collections will work, but you'll lose some of the benefits of defining objects with behaviour/polymorphism etc.

e.g.

```
List<Product> products = ...
products.add(new Book(...));
products.add(new Dvd(...));
```

(or perhaps a map of stock item id to object instance, or, or, or...)

I would treat JSON as a representation of your object (e.g. like XML). If you need to transport or store these objects, translate them to a format such as JSON or XML. But manage them within your program using objects with type and behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I looked into it. Can I use this MultiMap without a model class ?

Comment: You can use it with any object (subject to equals/hashCode being defined correctly)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I gave its documentation a quick read and I think this would be perfect.
One more thing, can I convert an sql resultset to a Guava MultiMap ?

Comment: I should think so. Perhaps simply iterate through the resultset, convert each row to an object and write it in given a suitable key

Answer (score 2):

You need a MultiMap, not present by default in Java but you can find it in libraries like Guava or Apache Commons.

Answer (score 0):

As @maskacovnik wrote- use your own class :)

Btw you can also work with *JSON in java* - [API docs there](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html)

> If you need some container you can use also a [hashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) - with all values saved as *string* eg.
>   (for multi-valued keys you can use value in format eg. csv ..)

Example of Hashmap data structure:

```
name - name
surname - surname
functions - func1;funct2,etc..
```

And while you will need to *read values of keys*, you can parse them into array by `string.split(regex)`